# Magento 1.7 Captcha module

Tags: magento, captcha, magento-1.7

In the new Magento release the captcha options in "System->Configurations->Customer Configuration->Captcha" I created a new form called "Signmeup"... but it does not seem to be working. I am having trouble getting it to show:

```
<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')
->createBlock('captcha/captcha_zend')
->setFormId('signmeup')
->setImgWidth(230)
->setImgHeight(50)
->setTemplate('captcha/zend.phtml')
->toHtml();?>
```

Right now that block is not being displayed on the page.
(Not a dynamic page... static page with core Mage Bootup)
Here is a screen shot of what I am talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After finding the captcha.xml code online (which for some reason was not in my enterprise), I created `captcha.xml` and pasted that code in the layout folder.

Next, I made sure every this was turned on in the `admin > Config > Customer config..`

I did have to add the the phtml files which I wanted the Captcha to show:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info');  (in php brackets.)
```

Once i did that everything was shown and functional.

Comment: Hi, all I am using Magento community edition 1.7.0.2 and I have enabled the captcha as shown in the image give above.But captcha is not visible on the front end.Do I need to make changes to some code? Please help

Comment: @Muk, how did you enable the CAPTCHA? My Customer Configuration doesn't have a CAPTCHA option, my last configuration gray bar is "Address Templates"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by creating a small module that adds the native captcha module to the product review form. The module consists of just a few files:

```
app/code/local/MyCompany/MyCaptcha/etc/config.xml
app/code/local/MyCompany/MyCaptcha/Model/Observer.php
app/etc/modules/MyCompany_MyCaptcha.xml
app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/mycaptcha.xml
```

Add the following code to the template (.phtml) file containing the form you wish to add the captcha to:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('captcha/captcha')
->setFormId('your_form_id')
->setImgWidht(230)
->setImgHeight(50)
->toHtml();
?>
```

change 'your_form_id' to whatever you'd like.
In **config.xml**:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_MyCaptcha>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </MyCompany_MyCaptcha>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mycaptcha> <!-- should be some unique name -->
                    <file>mycaptcha.xml</file>
                </mycaptcha>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <!--  Now we need to add our observer. I attached mine to the 
controller_action_predispatch_review_product_post event because 
I needed to intercept product review post event. The event you 
attach your observer to will be different depending on what you're 
trying to do. -->
    <global>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_review_product_post>
                <observers>
                    <mycaptcha> <!-- these need to match -->
                        <class>MyCompany_MyCaptcha_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>myMethod</method>
                    </mycaptcha>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_review_product_post>
        </events>
    </global>
    <!-- Now we add our form label that will show in configuration and allow
us to turn the captcha on or off. -->
    <default>
        <captcha>
            <frontend>
                <areas>
                    <mycaptcha> <!-- these need to match -->
                        <label>My Captcha</label>
                    </mycaptcha>
                </areas>
            </frontend>
        </captcha>
    </default>
</config>
```

That's it for **config.xml**
Now let's add our observer. The following code is from http://mustakarhu.com/blog/magento-captcha-extension-ajax/ and has only been slightly altered so shout out to them.

```
<?php
/**
* Break the execution in case of incorrect CAPTCHA  
*
* @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
* @return Cbad_Captcha_Model_Observer
*/

class MyModule_MyCaptcha_Model_Observer extends Mage_Captcha_Model_Observer
{

 public function myMethod($observer) { // called in config.xml
    $formId = 'your_form_id'; // you will change this value
    $captchaModel = Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($formId);
    $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
    $request = $controller->getRequest();
    if ($captchaModel->isRequired()) {

        $request->getPost(Mage_Captcha_Helper_Data::INPUT_NAME_FIELD_VALUE);
        if (!$captchaModel->isCorrect($this->_getCaptchaString($request, $formId))) {

            if((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')) {
                // Is ajax
                $action = $request->getActionName();
                Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->setFlag(
                        $action, Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);

                $controller->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(200);
                $controller->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

                $controller->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode(
                        array(
                            "msg" => Mage::helper('captcha')->__('Incorrect CAPTCHA.')
                        )
                    ));

            } else {
               // Is form submit
                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')
                    ->addError(Mage::helper('captcha')->__('Incorrect CAPTCHA.'));
                $controller->setFlag('', Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')
                    ->setCustomerFormData($controller->getRequest()->getPost());
                $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('*/*'));
            }
        }
    }

    return $this;
  }
}
?>
```

Most of the work is out of the way. I'll leave **MyCompany_MyCaptcha.xml** for you to figure out on your own (it's incredibly simple).
Onto **mycaptcha.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
        </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

This layout xml adds the necessary javascript to the head section on a product page. You will need to change the layout handle (catalog_product_view) to whatever page your form will be on.
I hope I covered everything in enough detail and someone will be able to adapt this to their own needs. 
Some other resources on this subject:

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/298363/
- http://razbakov.com/en/magento-native-captcha-for-contact-form/
- https://www.atwix.com/magento/captcha-in-magento/