# How to add Captcha on contact us page and below newsletter block

Tags: magento, captcha, newsletter

How to add captcha on contact us page and below newsletter block in magento 1.9.0.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:
[Magento 1.7 Captcha module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586267/magento-1-7-captcha-module)

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/contacts-form-captcha.html

> INSTRUCTIONS
>
> 1. Sign up for a reCAPTCHA account on http://www.google.com/recaptcha
> 2. Open configuration page of "Contacts Form Captcha": [Top menu of
>      Magento Store Admin Panel] System -> Configuration -> [select tab]
>      Contatcs -> [expand section] Contacts Form Captcha
> 3. Enable extension: "Enable Captcha" set to "Yes"
> 4. Enter the public and
>      private API keys from reCAPTCHA in "Public Key"/"Private Key" fields
> 5. [Optional] Select name of theme of reCAPTCHA widget (theme "Red" is
>      default)
> 6. [Optional] Select language which use for reCAPTCHA widget
>      (language "English" is default) Save Config

Comment: I want to add default captcha of magento below newsletter subscription on home page.